# How to send an email automatically to user when we enter them in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

We want to send an email automatically to users when we enter them in DE.

We tried to do it using triggered send but unable to do like how and where should we write the logic.

Comment: Would it be OK, if there w would be an hour of delay between the time the record enters the DE and the send? How are you entering the records?

Comment: @RafałWolsztyniak Yes, that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways how to do it and more or less always depends on your experience with MC and technical expertise.

For example, one of the easiest ways would be to create an Automation with either [SQL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) or [Filter Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_a_filter_activity.htm&type=5), which would prepare the data and also refresh it with new records.

Once this is configured, you would need to create a Multi-Step Journey where you would have pretty much only [Email Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_send_email_activity.htm&type=5).

- [**Entry Source**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_data_extension.htm&type=5) is going to be Data Extension that is updated in the Automation.
- **Schedule** of the Journey is going to be the [Automation's schedule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_schedule_an_automation.htm&type=5) from the previous step (thus configure the time and frequency of running in the automation and that is going to be the frequency of pushing new records to the Journey and sending them an email).
- [**Contact Entry**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_choose_a_contact_entry_mode.htm&type=5) should be selected yourself based on your structure and for example if there is a possibility to re-entry or if not, then how frequently you want to re-send the email to the contacts that have been in the Journey already.
- Consider the duration of the [**Wait Time Activity**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_activity.htm&type=5) if your contacts might re-enter.

And as a more complex and sophisticated way, you can have the same Journey but the Entry Source would be [API Event](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_api_entry_source_use_case_1.htm&type=5), which push contacts inside once called.

Comment: Could you please help me how can I filter the records which are recently added and not entered in the journey.  As you have mentioned, "For example, one of the easiest ways would be to create an Automation with either SQL or Filter Activity, which would prepare the data and also refresh it with new records."

Comment: Hello @Gxdev, it could be done on different levels. Either in the Journey that will have [settings to evaluate only new records only](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&type=5) or you can create a new date field that would have value of when the record got created and then your filter records in the SQL/Journey by it.